# How to create a batch that creates a directory named the current date and time, and then copy files in it?

Tags: date, time, directory, backup, auto

I have to seperate codes.
This creates a directory with only the date, but i don't know how to put the time on the end.

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims=" %%a in ('date /T') do set datestr=%%a
mkdir c:\%date:/=%
```

And I have this to copy the files:

```
robocopy "%appdata%\saves" "C:\Users\redfi\OneDrive\Savesbackup" /e /xf
```

They both work individually, but I want to put them in one batch.
I want it to create the directory with the current date and time, and then copy the saves in it. So I can restore older saves if I want.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out. You might need to edit the date formats.

```
echo off
set CUR_YYYY=%date:~0,4%
set CUR_MM=%date:~5,2%
set CUR_DD=%date:~8,2%
set CUR_HH=%time:~0,2%
if %CUR_HH% lss 10 (set CUR_HH=0%time:~1,1%)

set CUR_NN=%time:~3,2%
set CUR_SS=%time:~6,2%
set CUR_MS=%time:~9,2%

set SUBFILENAME=%CUR_YYYY%.%CUR_MM%.%CUR_DD%_%CUR_HH%.%CUR_NN%

mkdir C:\Users\redfi\OneDrive\Minecraftbackup\%SUBFILENAME%

robocopy "%appdata%\.minecraft\saves" "C:\Users\redfi\OneDrive\Minecraftbackup\%SUBFILENAME%" /e /xf
```